# Problems with tsbs/bootstrap and templating engine rendering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4, templating, package-managers

So, I'm trying to get a Bootstrap 4 development site running on Debian 9.  I've installed dependencies, and done backflips to try and get this running, but I keep getting the default index page that has an empty head (obviously causing problems with rendering as the jquery/bootstrap scaffolding is missing entirely.  Everything else is there, but it's like the head doesn't even get compiled or linked.

**Interestingly there is no `npm start` or some similar script in the package.json file.**

```
"scripts": {
"bundlesize": "bundlesize",
"css": "npm-run-all --parallel css-lint* css-compile* --sequential css-prefix* css-minify*",
"css-main": "npm-run-all --parallel css-lint css-compile --sequential css-prefix css-minify",
"css-docs": "npm-run-all --parallel css-lint-docs css-compile-docs --sequential css-prefix-docs css-minify-docs",
"css-compile": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap.scss dist/css/bootstrap.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-grid.scss dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css",
"css-compile-docs": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 assets/scss/docs.scss assets/css/docs.min.css",
"css-lint": "stylelint --syntax scss \"scss/**/*.scss\"",
"css-lint-docs": "stylelint --syntax scss \"assets/scss/*.scss\" && stylelint \"docs/**/*.css\"",
"css-lint-vars": "node build/lint-vars.js scss/ assets/scss/",
"css-prefix": "postcss --config build/postcss.config.js --replace \"dist/css/*.css\" \"!dist/css/*.min.css\"",
"css-prefix-docs": "postcss --config build/postcss.config.js --replace \"assets/css/docs.min.css\" \"docs/**/*.css\"",
"css-minify": "cleancss --level 1 --source-map --source-map-inline-sources --output dist/css/bootstrap.min.css dist/css/bootstrap.css && cleancss --level 1 --source-map --source-map-inline-sources --output dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css && cleancss --level 1 --source-map --source-map-inline-sources --output dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css",
"css-minify-docs": "cleancss --level 1 --source-map --source-map-inline-sources --output assets/css/docs.min.css assets/css/docs.min.css",
"js": "npm-run-all js-lint* js-compile js-minify",
"js-main": "npm-run-all js-lint js-compile js-minify",
"js-docs": "npm-run-all js-lint-docs js-minify-docs",
"js-lint": "eslint js/src js/tests build/",
"js-lint-docs": "eslint assets/js/ docs/ sw.js",
"js-compile": "npm-run-all --parallel js-compile-*",
"js-compile-standalone": "rollup --environment BUNDLE:false --config build/rollup.config.js --sourcemap",
"js-compile-bundle": "rollup --environment BUNDLE:true --config build/rollup.config.js --sourcemap",
"js-compile-plugins": "cross-env PLUGINS=true babel js/src/ --out-dir js/dist/ --source-maps",
"js-compile-plugins-coverage": "cross-env PLUGINS=true NODE_ENV=test babel js/src/ --out-dir js/coverage/dist/ --source-maps",
"js-minify": "npm-run-all --parallel js-minify-*",
"js-minify-standalone": "uglifyjs --compress typeofs=false --mangle --comments \"/^!/\" --source-map \"content=dist/js/bootstrap.js.map,includeSources,url=bootstrap.min.js.map\" --output dist/js/bootstrap.min.js dist/js/bootstrap.js",
"js-minify-bundle": "uglifyjs --compress typeofs=false --mangle --comments \"/^!/\" --source-map \"content=dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map,includeSources,url=bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map\" --output dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
"js-minify-docs": "uglifyjs --mangle --comments \"/^!/\" --output assets/js/docs.min.js assets/js/vendor/anchor.min.js assets/js/vendor/clipboard.min.js assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js \"assets/js/src/*.js\"",
"js-test": "npm-run-all --parallel js-test-karma*",
"js-test-karma": "karma start js/tests/karma.conf.js",
"js-test-karma-old": "cross-env USE_OLD_JQUERY=true npm run js-test-karma",
"js-test-karma-bundle": "cross-env karma start js/tests/karma-bundle.conf.js",
"js-test-karma-bundle-old": "cross-env USE_OLD_JQUERY=true npm run js-test-karma-bundle",
"js-test-cloud": "ruby -r webrick -e \"s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3000, :DocumentRoot => Dir.pwd, :Logger => WEBrick::Log.new('/dev/null'), :AccessLog => []); trap('INT') { s.shutdown }; s.start\" & node build/saucelabs-unit-test.js",
"docs": "npm-run-all --parallel css-docs js-docs --sequential docs-compile docs-lint",
"docs-compile": "bundle exec jekyll build",
"postdocs-compile": "npm run docs-workbox-precache",
"docs-github": "shx echo \"github: true\" > twbsconfig.yml && npm run docs-compile -- --config _config.yml,twbsconfig.yml && shx rm ./twbsconfig.yml",
"docs-github-serve": "bundle exec jekyll serve --skip-initial-build --no-watch",
"docs-lint": "npm-run-all docs-lint-*",
"docs-lint-htmllint": "htmllint --rc build/.htmllintrc \"_gh_pages/**/*.html\" \"js/tests/**/*.html\"",
"docs-lint-vnu-jar": "node build/vnu-jar.js",
"docs-serve": "bundle exec jekyll serve",
"docs-upload-preview": "build/upload-preview.sh",
"docs-workbox-precache": "node build/workbox.js",
"maintenance-dependencies": "ncu -a -x jquery && npm update && bundle update && shx echo \"Manually update assets/js/vendor/*, js/tests/vendor/* and .travis.yml\"",
"release-sri": "node build/generate-sri.js",
"release-version": "node build/change-version.js",
"release-zip": "cd dist/ && zip -r9 bootstrap-$npm_package_version-dist.zip * && shx mv bootstrap-$npm_package_version-dist.zip ..",
"dist": "npm-run-all --parallel css js",
"test": "npm-run-all dist js-test docs-compile docs-lint bundlesize",
"watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch-css watch-js",
"watch-css": "nodemon --ignore js/ --ignore dist/ -e scss -x \"npm run css\"",
"watch-js": "nodemon --ignore scss/ --ignore js/dist/ --ignore dist/ -e js -x \"npm run js-compile\""
}
```

I'm just stuck.  Is this a sass issue?  A build tooling issue?  Any decent (and thorough) tutorials of how to stitch this all together?

My initial scaffolding is using the twbs/bootstrap composer package.

I'm using NPM to install (node v8.11.3 / npm 5.6.0)

Any Jetbrains specifics that may be helpful?

Here's the Developer Tools view from Chrome besides the rendering.

[image: Blank Head Tag]

Here's the rest of the page.

[image]

Here's what happens when I click on a link.  The `{{xyz}}` tags tell me there is something not getting parsed/complied/linked (whatever the correct term in this context is.)

[image]

Here's my dir structure

[image: Directory Structure]

Just to eliminate some confusion on replies, here the default template, the `{{content}}` part, which is being rendered, but the `{%xyz%}` parts are missing, ie: the head.

[default template file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCxex.png)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of app you want to build?

How have you generated that project?

I would need to see your entry app point (app.js, server.js, etc)
What is happening is nodeJS is not rendering your templates

but I think what is misisng the view engine setter something like `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

[A simple tutorial to create Bootstrap web pages](https://www.codementor.io/codeforgeek/build-website-from-scratch-using-expressjs-and-bootstrap-du107sby7)

Comment: 1.) It's the basic starter scaffolding from twbs/bootstrap.

2.) It was generated from composer which internally uses npm to generate the file dependencies.

3.) That's part of the problem I've had debugging it, as there doesn't appear to be an entry point.  I'll post the package.json so you can see the available scripts.

Comment: Also it's importing the html body section just fine!